# How do I set an indeterminate height on a column that spans multiple rows with CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm using Tailwind CSS and attempting to use a grid layout which looks like below:

[image: my content layout]

I have some dashboard-type metrics in Div 1. Now, when I add a very long ordered list to Div 2, for some reason, it's stretching Div 1's height to (what appears to me) to be the overall height of Div 2.

Hopefully this screenshot makes clear what is happening. You can see the height of that top Div (Div 1) is enormous after adding the content to the right Div column:

[image: what happens when adding content to Div 2]

The code I've used is basically copy/pasted directly from a Tailwind Grid generator as shown below:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-4 gap-4">
    <div class="col-span-3">1</div>
    <div class="row-span-3 col-start-3 row-start-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-start-1 row-start-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-start-2 row-start-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-span-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 row-start-4">6</div>
</div>
```

I've simply placed my own content in their respective Div's, but it's behaving unexpectedly.

My goal is to basically have all Div's in the Grid have a height that is as big as the content in its respective Div.

EDIT: Similar to how this pen works. Although the pen uses custom css stylings. Ideally, I'd like to use the Tailwind CSS classes to achieve the same result.

https://codepen.io/source-matters/pen/YzJaBRL?editors=1100

Comment: What do you want the height of divs 3 onwards to be, given div 2 can have masses of content?

Comment: These should auto-fit to their content's height, maintaining the specified "gap", and alignment to the "top" (or "start").

Comment: So the layout could look different from that shown? That is, div 2 could be much taller, going below the bottom of div 5?

Comment: Correct - I suppose it makes sense now to make divs 3, 4, and 5's heights be to their content, and if Div 2 extends past that bottom div 6, that div 6 either stretches with div 2's height or not (i'd be happy either way).

Comment: I added a pen to the post that aims to give idea of what I'm after (although I'd like to achieve it with Tailwind classes).

Comment: From another SO post, I removed the "grid-rows-4" definition from the container, and that gets me kind of close. The top row stays content height now, but middle divs seem confused on how to "stretch". I can get them to be their content's heights, but the row below doesn't "move up" to meet them", they start where that long column ends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is because you have applied `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` via `grid-rows-4`. This instructs the layout that each track should be ¼ of the height. So if the last three row tracks are tall because of content, this will elongate the first row track so that it adheres to the ¼-height stipulation. Instead, you could consider telling the layout that the first row track should *not* be a fraction of the overall height at all:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-[auto_repeat(3,1fr)] gap-4">
    <div class="col-span-3 bg-red-200">1</div>
    <div class="row-span-3 col-start-3 row-start-2 bg-green-200">
      <div class="h-96">Foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-1 row-start-2 bg-yellow-200">3</div>
    <div class="col-start-2 row-start-2 bg-violet-200">4</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 bg-blue-200">5</div>
    <div class="col-span-2 row-start-4 bg-sky-200">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to tell it 3, 4, and 5 should be content height, and div 6 to "stretch" to match to the bottom of the long column?

Comment: I tested out the code you provided, but behaves the same. My layout looks identical to yours up until I put content in the actual right column. Once content is added, the column stretches, divs 3 and 4 stay the height of their content, , but 5 gets pushed way down (not up next to 3 and 4) and has a huge height even with no content. Div 6 properly stays tight to the bottom of 5, but also stretches (fine in this scenario). So still trying to get divs 3, 4, and 5 to be "content height" and keep 5 up tight to 3 and 4.

Comment: "Is there a way to tell it 3, 4, and 5 should be content height, and div 6 to "stretch" to match to the bottom of the long column?" Yep! Consider applying `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 1fr` via the `grid-rows-[repeat(3,auto)_1fr]` class: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Eini7FebQa

Comment: oh wow! that works perfect! I'm not familiar with that syntax at all (new to grid) - could you school me on the differences between your original code solution and that comment-based one, specifically the use of "_" and what the fr actually DOES? Thanks so much!!

Comment: "When an arbitrary value needs to contain a space, use an underscore (`_`) instead" (from [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)). "The `fr` unit represents a fraction of the leftover space in the grid container" (from [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex_value)).